# What would be enough or sufficient information to show that a certain point is a barycenter of a triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I posted a question on how to show that point was the barycenter of a triangle. I understood the process of the answer that they gave me, but don't know if the information is enough to show that point was the barycenterI since I don't know much about it. Here would be a drawing of what he basically did did:

[image]

He showed that $D$ was the midpoint of $BC$ and that $ \frac {BF}{BE}= \frac {2}{3}$. Would that be enough to show that $F$ is the barycenter?

Also if I have a point in a triangle the splits two lines (coming from two different vertices) into two segments with the proportion $1:2$ is that enough to say that that point is the barycenter?

Comment: If you pick a barycentric coordinate system, where $BC$ is the first axis and $BA$ the second axis, you have $B=(0,0)$, $C=(1,0)$, $A=(0,1)$, $D=(1/2, 0)$, $E=(1/2, 1/2)$, and the barycenter is at $(1/3, 1/3)$.  All three lines from a vertex to the midpoint of the opposite edge intersect at the barycenter, so any two of them are enough to prove the barycenter. The $BF / BE = 2 / 3$ is one solution for the barycenter; at $t=2/3$, $(1-t)B + tE = (1-t)B + t((A+C)/2) = (1/3, 1/3)$. Unfortunately, I'm not a mathematician, and don't know if this is an acceptable proof!

Answer (score 1):

The barycenter divides each median into two parts, one the double of the other. Hence if $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$ and $\frac{BF}{BE}=\frac {2}{3}$, then $F$ is the barycenter.

If instead you know that $FE/BF=FD/AF=1/2$, then triangles $BAF$ and $DEF$ are similar with $DE/AB=1/2$ and $DE\parallel AB$. It follows that triangles $ABC$ and $EDC$ are also similar and $DC/BC=EC/AC=1/2$. Hence $AD$ and $BE$ are medians and $F$ is the barycenter.

Answer (score 0):

Draw median $\overline{BE'}$ and let $G = \overline{BE'} \cap \overline{AD} $. Suppose that $E' \neq E$.

Then $BG/BE = BF/BE$, and thus $\triangle FBG \sim \triangle EBE'$. This implies $\angle BGF = \angle BE'E$, or that $\overline{GF} \parallel \overline{E'E}$, which is false since $\overline{GF}$ and $\overline{E'E}$ intersect at $A$.

Thus, $E' = E$, so $\overline{BE}$ is a median. Then $F = \overline{BE} \cap \overline{AD}$ is the barycenter.

Comment: Yes you can. Look at the ratios; the two triangles are homothetic with center $B$.

$BG$ corresponds to $BE'$ and $BF$ corresponds to $BE$, therefore the two triangles must be scaled copies of each other, so $\angle BGF$ does in fact equal $\angle BE'E$.

Comment: That is why I put $\triangle FBG \sim \triangle EBE'$ and not $\triangle GBF \sim \triangle EBE'$ to show the correspondence.

Comment: Your second comment is in regard to my first question, isn´t it? but what about my first question (when the a point splits two lines into the proportion $1:2$)?